# Не устанавливается библиотека Pytesseract в Python3.9.0

Tags: python, tesseract, python-3.9

Пытаюсь установить библиотеку pytesseract.

Выполняю:

```
pip install pytesseract

brew pip install tesseract

pip install tesseract
```

Не работает все равно.

Comment: А какие ошибки в консоли при установке? 
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pytesseract, since package 'wheel' is not installed.?

Comment: Ошибок в консоли нет. При запуске программы выходит ошибка, что модуль tesseract не установлен. При повторной установке пишет, что такой модуль уже присутствует.

Comment: Приложите свой код. Какой IDE вы используете?

Comment: Использую IDE - vscode

Comment: код простой, даже если в нем одна строчка import pytesseract

Comment: Т.е. у вас была проблема не "не устанавливается", а "не импортируется". Учитесь правильно описывать проблему, это в разы повышает вероятность и скорость получения полезных советов.

Comment: Был написан итог: Не работает все равно. То есть код любой с этой библиотекой не работал. Импорт в первую очередь. Отчасти Вы правы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалось решить проблему, установив еще библиотеку pytesseract-ocr через анаконду (после библиотеки pytesseract).